# Elasticsearch aggregation performance for more than 24 hrs on 200-300GB and 50M data

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-8

We are using ES 8.3.3 with local ssd based VMs in Oracle Kubernetes engine.
stack infra is as following:
master: 3 nodes, 5cpu, 16gb
data: : 6 nodes, 10 cpu, 60gb, heap - 30gb, 5TB ssd each
coordinating: 3 nodes, 10 cpu, 60gb

We have a particular index with 200-300 gb, 6 shards, 1 replica, 10M docs.
this index has a field over which unique count aggregation is being done, and its taking time around 22-25 seconds for last 24hrs and returning 1M unique results.
but while we do the same query for more than 24hrs it times out.

Please suggest next steps to be taken.
we have followed everything said here:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-the-performance-of-high-cardinality-terms-aggregations-in-elasticsearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/system-config.html

Comment: Have you tried using [async search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/async-search.html)

Comment: Async search is not an option for us, as we are using grafana dashboards and it uses elasticsearch plugin, which might be using search api

Comment: Without the data, I is more difficult to elaborate a great solution. Maybe with transform ?